# How do you loop check a text in php

Tags: php

i am making a code where the system checks if you are an 'Admin' or a 'SuperAdmin'.

i cant seem to make it loop everything to check if 'SuperAdmin' is in the 'user_type'

```
$sql = "SELECT * from users";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {




if ($row2['user_type'] != "SuperAdmin") {

           echo "<script>window.alert('You do not have administrative 
priviledges for this page!');
              location.href='../admin_page.php';</script>";

    } else {

    }

}
```

Comment: Learn how to use `echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump`, etc.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to find out what `$row2` and specifically `$row2['user_type']` contain?

Comment: You are aware that your code isn't going to check if the current user is a SuperAdmin, right? You're looping through every single user so your "if" statement will always be true and execute that javascript as long as you have a single user which isn't SuperAdmin in your table

Comment: you also have to store the value of userRole in $_SESSION[] & check it.

Answer (score 0):

window.alert("You do not have administrative priviledges for this page!"); location.href="../admin_page.php";';
} else {

    }

?>

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to check if the current use is an "Admin" or a "SuperAdmin". In that case, you need to get the row for the current user using the UserID that you get after authenticating the user. Change your query and php code to something like:

```
$UserId = 111; //This is the user id from database you get on authenticating the user: e.g. 111. 
$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE UserId = ". $UserId;   
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); //This should retrieve a single row, with details for the specific user.
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if !(($row2['user_type'] == "SuperAdmin")||($row2['user_type'] == "Admin")){
           echo "<script>window.alert('You do not have administrative 
priviledges for this page!');
              location.href='../admin_page.php';</script>";

    } else {
          //Code to be executed if the user is an admin or a super admin
    }
}
```